# Is there a python equivalent to the "split" argument in R's summary.aov()?

Tags: python, r, statsmodels, anova

I am using python to conduct a two-way ANOVA that includes two variables (`var_A` and `var_B`) and their interaction (`var_A:var_B`). Variable A is a variable with three levels and variable B is an ordered categorical variable with three levels. I am looking to get the F stats for the orthogonal polynomial contrasts for variable B.

I would typically do this type of analysis in R, but I am working with others who prefer Python.

In R, after setting up the `aov` model with the right contrasts, I would do something like the following to split up the sum of squares for `var_B` to get an ANOVA table with separate F stats reported for each contrast. More details and examples on using the R `summary.aov` function can be found [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.1/topics/summary.aov).

```
# Create data
df <- data.frame(target = c(449, 413, 326, 409, 358, 291, 341, 278, 312),
                 var_A = rep(c(1, 2, 3), each = 3),
                 var_B = rep(c(1, 2, 3), 3))

# Make var_B an ordered factor
df$var_B <- factor(df$var_B, ordered = TRUE)

# Set contrasts
options(contrasts=c('contr.sum','contr.poly'))

# Create model
aov_model <- aov(target ~ var_A * var_B, data = df)

# Run summary with the F-test shown for the orthogonal polynomial contrasts
summary(aov_model, 
        split = list(var_B = list(linear = 1, quadratic = 2)))
```

Does anyone know if it's possible to do the same thing in Python?

As of right now, I am able to add in the right contrasts for `var_B` using the `Poly()` function from the `patsy` package. I see the contrasts in the summary of my linear model, and I am able to generate the ANOVA table with the overall effect of `var_B`.

However, I am unsure of how to "split" the sum of squares for `var_B` in the ANOVA table to see the F-statistics for each of the contrasts.

```py
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

from patsy.contrasts import Poly

# Create data frame
df = pd.DataFrame({'target': [449, 413, 326, 409, 358, 291, 341, 278, 312],
                  'var_A': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
                  'var_B': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]})

# Fit the linear model
overall_model = smf.ols(formula= "target ~ var_A * C(var_B, Poly())",
                        data=df).fit()

# Conduct an ANOVA on the model
overall_anova = sm.stats.anova_lm(overall_model, type=3, robust="hc3")
```

Is there an argument I can pass to the `sm.stats.anova_lm()` function to split up the sum of squares? Or is there another way to break up the effect into the orthogonal contrasts?

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Can you show the rest of the R code including data and model?

Comment: @Parfait - I've added the rest of the R code